# How to get the visited website URL's in a system in C#

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net

I want to get the website urls visited in a system through VB.Net.
One exe should run in the background when windows starts and it should
record all the visited website urls.

Even if the user clears the history, cache i want all the urls.
Once if the browser requests an url it should be recorded.

I trie with this code

> Private Function RunScript(ByVal scriptText As String) As String

```
  Dim MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
  MyRunSpace.Open()
  Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()
  MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText)
  MyPipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String")
  Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()
  MyRunSpace.Close()
  Dim MyStringBuilder As New StringBuilder()
  For Each obj As PSObject In results
    MyStringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString())
  Next
 Return MyStringBuilder.ToString()

End Function
```

In that scriptText is :-

> "ipconfig /displaydns | select-string 'Record Name' | foreach-object { $_.ToString().Split(' ')[-1]}"

This is giving website url's but lot of other things are also there.
And some are missing, working oly in windows 7.

How to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps try to find out where the url history is hidden of the browser and try to "get" all those items every now and again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a network sniffer. Read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C) article for more information on how to write it using C#. You can always use `C#` to `VB.Net` converter [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to convert code.

Comment: But in that how get the URL like [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946984/how-to-get-the-visited-website-urls-in-a-system-in-c-sharp . as visited URL say..

Comment: URL is an IP address. You can always get host name as described in response to http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/578730-how-get-host-name-ip-address question. The article captures the IP address, you can tweak code to display host names instead. It was a guideline matching to your requirement. You will need to tweak code to completely fit your requirements. Hope it helps !